# Is PascalScript compatible with Delphi XE5 to create Android/iOS/Windows applications?

Tags: android, delphi, pascalscript, delphi-xe5

I want to create an application that will draw simple forms based on JSON data. I need to have a script to put intelligence on that.

Is Pascal Script from RemObjects a solution for that?

Is is compatible to generate application with the same source code for Android, iOS and Windows?

EDIT: Extending to better understand the need: I have a delphi program that draws a form (pretty much like a dfm file, as a descriptor)  and fill it with data from a database. However there is a need for inteligence to validate the data entered. Since the form and data and the validation rules are done by the user there is no way to be a "regular" pascal source code. For that an script language would be perfect, and since I need the same form and same script works in each platform that I could delploy my application it would be also perfect.

This script language should be able to work with exposed objects and deal with database operations (via exposed objects should work also), it is not only a simple IF statement, but there is not need of classes definition. Basically the same concept of what is possible to be done inside a delphi event when attributed by the IDE on OnClick for a TButton for example. It can validate fields, make a calculation of totals, save to a database.

EDIT: I have found that http://www.paxcompiler.com/ PaxCompiler is capable of implement scripting on all target platforms of XE5. I have contacted all the other scripting around this is the only one up to now.

Comment: No evidence in the repo of any support for mobile compilers.

Comment: Since the script doesn't run in the web browser, why not write native (compiled) code? Please explain your requirements further.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: I have added the overall concept on the question to help clarify. Thanks

Comment: You might not need a full blown script language. And why not pick something more mainstream than pascal?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: so, what would you recommend that I could use in delphi that can be cross platform (XE5 could compile for all platforms using same source code) ??

Comment: Don't want to recommend anything without knowing the problem. Not enough detail here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you mind on help me on open my eyes on what I should add to the description that I could describe better the problem, for me it seems to be describing the problem, however my english knowledges is not good.

Comment: The point I wanted to make is that if the validation is simple enough then you don't need a general purpose programming language.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have updated the edit. It is not that simple what I need. There is need to do the operations of a procedural language. No need of OOP. Pretty much what VB and Pascal where capable before OOP. (however access exposed objects would be great)

Comment: I suspect you've got a lot of work ahead of you if you really do need all of that. Are the users going to write the code on their phones, or are you going to supply it? I cannot help thinking that trying to do this with a Pascal language is not very realistic. One language that readily runs on all those platforms is Javascript.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is there a javascript interpreter / parser that can I use on my delphi source code? Is there something like IActiveScriptSite, or component, that I could use from my source code in Delphi that can compatible with XE5 for android and IOs either?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are getting at there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw shapes based on JSON data, then just interpret the data using Delphi code and have Delphi to draw the shapes or create the controls.

However I think it is a better idea to create some dummy code and ask RemObject support.
See: http://www.remobjects.com/support/

You can write them an email with some source/pseudo code of what you're trying to do and see what they say.

Comment: Delphi will interpret the data and actually not draw shape, but create controls, like TEdit and TLabels, creating like a form. However i need to validate the data localy and for that I need some kind of script. And that script parser and engine I believe need to be written on delphi either, since I need it working on Android/IOs/Windows based on Delphi XE5 cross compiler.

Comment: No, you can do that in Delphi itself, no need for script.

Comment: I need that the USER creates the scripting for validate the data. This is why I cannot use the delphi code itself. The validation are rules defined by the user and is related to each form created. There is no way to know in advance.