# Is DWScript compatible to create Delphi XE5 code for Android and IOs?

Tags: delphi, scripting, delphi-xe5, dwscript

Can I use DWScript classes in a Delphi XE5 program to run under Android and/or IOs and make the scripting works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is PascalScript compatible with Delphi XE5 to create Android/iOS/Windows applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124520/is-pascalscript-compatible-with-delphi-xe5-to-create-android-ios-windows-applica). If you want to try each and every scripting library to see if it works, **write some test code** and test them. Expecting us to do so for you isn't quite how SO works.

Comment: @KenWhite Well, I am not expecting to anyone testing for me, but since there is so many people around here that know things that could give a direction. My intention is to give the best try and actually post the results, since I am getting benefits from SO. AND I went to dwscript site and they explicit states to post here any question, so I believed one of the developers will take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Android and iOS compilers are not supported.

There are a few issues that prevent that at the moment

- I don't have access to those compilers
- There were some dropped Delphi features (like UTF8String) and there are some architectural changes (like ARC) which could make the adaptation non-trivial
- AFAIK the Apple licensing terms forbid use of 3rd party script engines in iOS, you're supposed to use the JavaScript one they provide, and only it.

Comment: I did not know about the script limitation in iOS. So Mono apps (Xamarin) are not identified as script engines in iOS?

Comment: ARC has been abandonned in most recent Delphi